# Button on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I'm trying to make a simple game which uses Canvas and I want to put there something like a button into the right upper corner which allows you to pause the game.
What would be the best way to do that?

I was thinking about drawing those two lines that symbolize pausing on the canvas and pausing the game after the player clicks its locations but isn't there a better way?

I put here also a picture to show you how I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use relative layout to manage all of the things.

1) find the relative layout

2) add something in your RelativeLayout

3) add the canvas to your RelativeLayout

My example below draws four buttons by simple for loop and add the canvas.

Example:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bb);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i);
    btn.setText("some_text");
    btn.setHeight(i*100);
    btn.setX(100*i);
    btn.setY(100*i);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
YourDesign abc=new YourDesign(this);
layout.addView(abc);
```

You could consider "YourDesign" is the class of your canvas.

Canvas example:

```
public class YourDesign extends View{

Bitmap picture;
int x=0;

public YourDesign(Context context) {
    super(context);
    picture=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(picture, x, 100, new Paint());
    x++;
    if(x>canvas.getWidth())
        x=0;
    invalidate();
}
```